# Attempting to parse XML using SAX, but none of my JUnit tests work?

Tags: java, xml, junit, sax

So I'm attempting to run various tests to check that my XML parsing is correct. Unfortunately none of them pass which I assume is due to the fact my XML file isn't being stored correctly to the ArrayList. I'd appreciate any help!

VideoFile.java:

```
package server;

public class VideoFile {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String filename;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }
    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }  
}
```

XMLReader.java:

```
package server;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;



public class XMLReader extends DefaultHandler {

    //List to hold VideoFiles object
    private List<VideoFile> videoList = null;
    private VideoFile emp = null;


    //getter method for employee list
    public List<VideoFile> getList() {
        return videoList;
    }


    boolean bTitle = false;
    boolean bFilename = false;


    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
            //create a new VideoFile and put it in Map
            String id = attributes.getValue("id");
            //initialize VideoFile object and set id attribute
            emp = new VideoFile();
            emp.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
            //initialize list
            if (videoList == null)
                videoList = new ArrayList<>();
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            //set boolean values for fields, will be used in setting VideoFile variables
            bTitle = true;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("filename")) {
            bFilename = true;
        }    
    }


    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
            //add VideoFile object to list
            videoList.add(emp);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        if (bTitle) {
            emp.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
            bTitle = false;
        } else if (bFilename) {
            emp.setFilename(new String(ch, start, length));
            bFilename = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader handler = new XMLReader();
        saxParser.parse(new File("videoList.xml"), handler);
        //Get VideoFiles list
        List<VideoFile> videoList = handler.getList();
        //print employee information
        for(VideoFile emp : videoList)
            System.out.println(emp);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

XMLReaderTest.java:

```
package server;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class XMLReaderTest {
    private XMLReader reader;
    private List<VideoFile> videoList;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        reader = new XMLReader();
        videoList = reader.getList();
    }

    @Test
    public void createListOfVideos() {
        assertTrue(videoList instanceof List);
    }

    @Test
    public void listContainsVideoFiles() {
        assertTrue(videoList.get(0) instanceof VideoFile);
    }

    @Test
    public void videoFileReturnsCorrectFields() {
        VideoFile videoFile = videoList.get(0);
        assertNotNull(videoFile.getId());
        assertNotNull(videoFile.getTitle());
        assertNotNull(videoFile.getFilename());
    }

    @Test
    public void videoFileReturnsCorrectData() {
        VideoFile videoFile = videoList.get(0);
        assertEquals("201202132", videoFile.getId());
        assertEquals("Monsters Inc.", videoFile.getTitle());
        assertEquals("monstersinc_high.mpg", videoFile.getFilename());
    }
}
```

videoList.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<videoList version="sample">
    <video id="4352524242">
        <title>Video 1</title>
        <filename>vid1_high.mpg</filename>
    </video>
    <video id="20120102b7">
        <title>Video 2</title>
        <filename>vid2-featurehp.mp4</filename>
    </video>
    <video id="1242102b7">
        <title>Vid3</title>
        <filename>vid3-featureukFhp.mp4</filename>
    </video>
</videoList>
```

Comment: With JAXB your code would be much more simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests are failing because your code does not parse the XML and your list of videos is left at null.  Your XML document is valid, but the code that parses it isn't being run.

The only code that parses the XML document is in the `main` method of `XMLReader`.  Because `XMLReader` isn't the main class (the main class will be a JUnit test runner class), it's `main` method is ignored.

Move the XML handling code out of the `main` method and ensure that your test calls it.

Comment: Sorry for the reply and thanks for your help! I've update the code and now it executes perfectly. Now onto the tests, what my lecturer has done doesn't quite make sense to me. I don't understand why he is loading up the XML file again separately when it's already loaded in XMLReader? How can I use the test cases to compare against the ArrayList that's generated, rather than the file directly?

Comment: @user1929131: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Your tests *are* comparing against the `ArrayList` that was returned from the XMLReader.

Comment: It seems the tests don't actually work, which is confusing me. So the first test, createListOfVideos, fails but all the others just give errors. The errors seem to occur because of:
VideoFile videoFile = videoList.get(0); which means that it can't return the element at said index?

Comment: Could it be because when the test runs, the List isn't actually being created, because the main code hasn't been run?

Comment: @user1929131: The list isn't being created.  If `videoList instanceof List` is false, `videoList` must be `null`.  Your other tests will report errors because you don't have any list to read video files out of.  If the code that parses the XML is still in `main`, then it won't run when you run the tests, because the code in your `main` method only runs if you run `XMLReaderTest` directly.